# How is this expression evaluated? "f" in "foo" == True

Tags: python, operator-precedence

```
>>> "f" in "foo"
True
>>> "f" in "foo" == True
False
```

I'm confused why the second expression is False. I see `==` has higher precedence than `in`. But then I would expect to get an exception, which is what happens when I add parentheses:

```
>>> "f" in ("foo" == True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

It seems the expression is only True when `foo` is on both sides of `==`, like so:

```
>>> "f" in "foo" == "foo"
True
>>> "f" in "foo" == "bar"
False
```

What am I missing? What is Python actually calculating here?

Comment: "I see == has higher precedence than in" - `in` and `==` have equal precedence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python, comparison operators chain.

That is why `1 < 2 < 3 < 4` works and evaluates to True.

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

`in` and `==` are such operators, so by this mechanism

```
"f" in "foo" == True
```

means

```
("f" in "foo") and ("foo" == True)
```